# emacs keybinding of alt-f4

Tags: emacs

Is it possible for `M-f4` to first close the frames until there is only one frame left and them close emacs all together?

I did bind `delete-frame` to `M-f4` but i keep forgetting that M-f4 doesn't close emacs, and I don't want to bind `M-f4` to `kill-emacs` as I keep using `M-f4` to close frames.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method, when bound to C-x C-c, allows you to close an emacs frame the 
same way, whether it's the sole window you have open, or whether it's
a "child" frame of a "parent" frame.  If you're like me, and use emacs in
a windowing environment, you probably have lots of frames open at any given
time.  Well, it's a pain to remember to do Ctrl-x 5 0 to dispose of a child
frame, and to remember to do C-x C-x to close the main frame (and if you're
not careful, doing so will take all the child frames away with it).  This
is my solution to that: an intelligent close-frame operation that works in 
all cases (even in an emacs -nw session).

```
(defun intelligent-close ()
  "quit a frame the same way no matter what kind of frame you are on"
  (interactive)
  (if (eq (car (visible-frame-list)) (selected-frame))
      ;;for parent/master frame...
      (if (> (length (visible-frame-list)) 1)
          ;;close a parent with children present
   (delete-frame (selected-frame))
        ;;close a parent with no children present
 (save-buffers-kill-emacs))
    ;;close a child frame
    (delete-frame (selected-frame))))
```

http://www.dotemacs.de/dotfiles/BenjaminRutt.emacs.html

Comment: How is this better than
`(if (cdr (frame-list))    (delete-frame (selected-frame))    (save-buffers-kill-emacs))` (which I wrote at the time of Emacs 19, so it may miss out on later refinements)?

Comment: @Gilles I dunno. I don't actually *know* elisp so I can't judge which is better. I just found the above in that person's .emacs and since it works, I just took it. And since I havn't found any problems with it, I'm using it.